# Several subscriptions at once from Phoenix channels

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework, channel

In a Rails channel I can subscribe user for several subscriptions at once like this:

```
def subscribed
  [1, 2, 3].each do |subscription|
    stream_for subscription
  end
end
```

And now the user has three subscriptions "my_channel:1", "my_channel:2", "my_channel:3". I do not need to receive any data from my front-end to subscribe my user this way.
But it seems that I can't do this from a Phoenix channel. It uses data, that Phoenix receives from js:

```
def join("mytopic:" <> subtopic, _params, socket) do
  {:ok, socket}
end
```

Is there a way to subscribe a user with some arbitrary topic name (for example, names come from database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section on [Subscribing to external topics](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.0-rc.1/Phoenix.Channel.html#module-subscribing-to-external-topics) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much!